# How to use linked in login for https server?

Tags: php, codeigniter, linkedin-api

Previously i was used http server for my linkedin login. Now I changed https server for my entire site. But now i cannot show login details after changed that. Here i post my function, In this fuction i also changed https. But yet not i show the details. I use this function in codeigniter.

```
public function login(){
    $client_id = $this->config->item('linkedin_app_id');
    $redirect_uri = base_url().'linkedinLogin';

    if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
        echo $_GET['error'] . ': ' . $_GET['error_description'];
    } elseif (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $this->loginAccessToken();
        $user = $this->login_fetch('GET', '/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,email-address,picture-url)');//get name
        $email = $user->emailAddress;
        $user_name = $user->firstName;
        $last_name = $user->lastName;
        $social_id = $user->id;
        $profile_image_url = 'user-thumb.png';
        echo "<pre>";print_r($user); die;
        if($email != '')
    {
        $googleLoginCheck = $this->user_model->googleLoginCheck($email);


        if($googleLoginCheck > 0)
        {
            //echo "login";
            $getGoogleLoginDetails = $this->user_model->google_user_login_details($email);
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($getGoogleLoginDetails);die;

            $userdata = array(
                        'fc_session_user_id' => $getGoogleLoginDetails['id'],

                        'session_user_email' => $getGoogleLoginDetails['email'] 
            );
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($userdata);die;
            $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);

            if($this->data['login_succ_msg'] != '')
            $lg_err_msg = $this->data['login_succ_msg'];
            else
            $lg_err_msg = 'You are Logged In ...';
            $this->setErrorMessage('success',$lg_err_msg);
            redirect(base_url());
        }
        else
        {

            $google_login_details = array('social_login_name'=>$user_name,'social_login_unique_id'=>$social_id,'screen_name'=>$user_name,'social_image_name'=>'','social_email_name'=>$email,'loginUserType'=>'google');
            //echo "<pre>";print_r($google_login_details);die;
            //echo "redirect to registration page";
            $social_login_name = $user_name;
            $this->session->set_userdata($google_login_details);


            $firstname = $user_name;
            $lastname = $last_name;
            $orgPass = time();
            $pwd = md5($orgPass);
            $Confirmpwd = $orgPass;
            $username = $user_name;

            $condition = array ('email' => $email);
            $duplicateMail = $this->user_model->get_all_details ( USERS, $condition );

            $expireddate = date ( 'Y-m-d', strtotime ( '+15 days' ) );

            $dataArr = array('firstname'=>$firstname,'lastname'=>$lastname,'user_name'=>$firstname,'group'=>'User','image'=>$profile_image_url,'email'=>$email,'password'=>$pwd,'status'=>'Active','expired_date'=>$expireddate,'is_verified'=>'No','loginUserType'=>'linkedin','google'=>'Yes','created'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $this->user_model->simple_insert(USERS,$dataArr);
            $lstID = $this->db->insert_id();
            //echo $this->db->last_query(); die;
            $userdata = array (
                    'quick_user_name' => $firstname,
                    'quick_user_email' => $email,
                    'fc_session_user_id' => $lstID,
                    'session_user_email' => $email 
            );
            $this->session->set_userdata ( $userdata );

            $this->setErrorMessage('success','Registered & Login Successfully');
            redirect(base_url());


        }
    }
    else
        {
        redirect('');
        }
    }else {
        header("Location:https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&state=987654321&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_share");
    }
}

public function loginAccessToken() {
$params = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'client_id' => $this->config->item('linkedin_app_id'),
    'client_secret' => $this->config->item('linkedin_app_key'),
    'code' => $_GET['code'],
    'redirect_uri' => base_url().'linkedinLogin'
);
// Access Token request
$url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?' . http_build_query($params);
// Tell streams to make a POST request
$context = stream_context_create(
        array('https' =>
            array('method' => 'POST',
            )
        )
);
// Retrieve access token information
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
// Native PHP object, please
$token = json_decode($response);
// Store access token and expiration time
$_SESSION['access_token'] = $token->access_token; // guard this! 
$_SESSION['expires_in'] = $token->expires_in; // relative time (in seconds)
$_SESSION['expires_at'] = time() + $_SESSION['expires_in']; // absolute time
return true;
}

public function login_fetch($method, $resource, $body = '') {
$opts = array(
    'https' => array(
        'method' => $method,
        'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . 
        $_SESSION['access_token'] . "\r\n" . 
        "x-li-format: json\r\n"
    )
);
$url = 'https://api.linkedin.com' . $resource;
 // if (count($params)) {
 //   $url .= '?' . http_build_query($params);
// }
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
return json_decode($response);
}
```

Here look the login() fuction. I print the user details. But i got empty window only

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($user); die;
```

But when i use http, i got the user details. Can help me anyone?